# How to filter numpy arrays with conditions on element properties, not just values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I want to filter a numpy array based on value conditions, I can do:

```py
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
filtered = arr[arr > 2] # [3, 4]
```

What if my elements have certain properties I wish to filter? Like this:

```py
arr = np.array([1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4])
filtered = arr[len(arr) > 2]
# this does not output the desired [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]], but rather [arr]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can vectorize the `len` function and use it on any array you want:

```
In [25]: vv = np.vectorize(len)                                                                                                                                                                             

In [26]: vv(arr)                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[26]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [28]: arr[vv(arr)>2]                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[28]: array([list([3, 3, 3]), list([4, 4, 4, 4])], dtype=object)
```

Or:

```
In [29]: vv = np.vectorize(lambda x: len(x)>2)                                                                                                                                                              

In [30]: arr[vv(arr)]                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[30]: array([list([3, 3, 3]), list([4, 4, 4, 4])], dtype=object)
```

And a bencmark (with current array):

```
In [29]: vv = np.vectorize(lambda x: len(x)>2)                                                                                                                                                              

In [30]: arr[vv(arr)]                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[30]: array([list([3, 3, 3]), list([4, 4, 4, 4])], dtype=object)

In [31]: %timeit arr[vv(arr)]                                                                                                                                                                               
31.6 µs ± 385 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [32]: vv = np.vectorize(len)                                                                                                                                                                             

In [33]: %timeit arr[vv(arr)>2]                                                                                                                                                                             
35 µs ± 578 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Note: This is an answer merely to your particular situation, but one can argue that you might need to change your data structure or any other change in your code in general. All these propositions are considerable but one thing that you must always note is that sometimes rethinking the question title will make the problem much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
In [7]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                      

In [8]: arr = np.array([[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]])                                                                                                                  

In [9]: check = np.vectorize(lambda element : len(element) > 2)                                                                                                                 

In [10]: arr[check(arr)]                                                                                                                                                        
Out[10]: array([list([3, 3, 3]), list([4, 4, 4, 4])], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example produces an error:

```
In [139]: arr = np.array([1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4])                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-139-f49650a95073> in <module>
----> 1 arr = np.array([1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4])

TypeError: array() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Did you intend to produce an object dtype array:

```
In [139]: arr = np.array([1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4])                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-139-f49650a95073> in <module>
----> 1 arr = np.array([1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4])

TypeError: array() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
In [140]: arr = np.array([[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]])                                                
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  #!/usr/bin/python3
In [141]: arr                                                                                                   
Out[141]: 
array([list([1]), list([2, 2]), list([3, 3, 3]), list([4, 4, 4, 4])],
      dtype=object)
```

(This future warning is produce by 1.19dev.)

For most purposes an object dtype array is more like a list than a numeric array.  Thus we could use a list comprehension to find the longer lists:

```
In [143]: [a for a in arr if len(a)>2]                                                                          
Out[143]: [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]

In [146]: timeit [a for a in arr if len(a)>2]                                                                   
1.36 µs ± 3.52 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

===

Others have suggested `np.vectorize`.  That's slower.

```
In [144]: np.vectorize(lambda a: len(a)>2)(arr)                                                                 
Out[144]: array([False, False,  True,  True])
In [145]: arr[np.vectorize(lambda a: len(a)>2)(arr)]                                                            
Out[145]: array([list([3, 3, 3]), list([4, 4, 4, 4])], dtype=object)

In [147]: timeit arr[np.vectorize(lambda a: len(a)>2)(arr)]                                                     
32.3 µs ± 128 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The list comprehension is even faster if it operates on a list rather than array:

```
In [148]: %%timeit alist=arr.tolist() 
     ...: [a for a in alist if len(a)>2]                                                                                                        
626 ns ± 2.41 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Lists can be faster than numpy arrays.

I only recommend `np.vectorize` for cases where you need to take advantage of its ability to 'broadcast' several arrays to a function that only works with scalar arguments.  It is not an effective alternative to a simple iteration.